# Structure/Model for first order language

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic

For simplicity lets say $L$ is a first order language with a single function symbol $f$ and no other nonlogical symbols

What would a structure/model, $M$ say, for $L$ look like? I know $M$ has some non-empty domain but Im confused about whether $M$ would contain both the symbol $f$ and a new symbol $f^m$ for the interpretation of f in M or would it just contain the interpretation symbol. Which of these is in the domain?

Thanks

Comment: $f$ is the *symbol* of the language $L$ and $f^M$ is the *object* of the structure $M$ interpreting it. Thus, if $|M|$ is the domain of the structure $M$, then $f^M : |M| \to |M|$, i.e. $f^M$ is a *function* in the set-theoretic sense.

Answer (score 1):

A structure in this language would consist of

- a domain $D$, and
- a function $D\to D$ that is the interpretation of $f$.

If you want to be completely formal of it, the structure would probably have the domain, then a map that maps the symbol $f$ to the function that interprets it, and then the empty map (for mapping the non-existent constant symbols of the language to their interpretations). But these nitty-gritty details depend a lot on how exactly your textbook/lecturer has chosen to set up things, and they are not really important.

Comment: Im still a little confused, maybe if i ask about constant symbols it will help. Lets say $L$ also has a constant symbol $c$, now what needs to be added to the structure?

Comment: @ConnorBishop: An element of $D$ that will serve as the interpretation of the new constant symbol.

Comment: And does the structure contain $c$ at all or only the interpretation of it?

Comment: @ConnorBishop: That depends on the nitty-gritty details of the particular formalization you're working with. In the formalization I find most natural, the structure would formally have a map in it that maps the symbol $c$ to the element that is its interpretation -- but, for example, if you're working with an _ordered_ vocabulary, the interpretation of $c$ would just be identified by its location within the tuple that formally constitutes the structure.